# SharePoint Online Calendar Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, item-level-permissions

Is it possible to only allow the author of a calendar item to edit the event? 
I have gone through advanced settings and selected "Create items and edit items that were created by the user" but other users are still able to edit the event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is Possible. Go to site content create new calendar app.
in newly created Calender--> go to setting --> Permission for this list and create unique permission with the creator having Full permission and every other member Read-only permission.
This calendar is good to go now all you need is to add this calendar to the page. go to the page--> Edit the page then add the web part called Event
[image]

change the setting as your desire 
[image]

and you are done